# list.sort() does not return the sorted list

Tags: python

I'm beginning python and am a little confused about why the following outputs `None`:

```
x= [3,1,2]
y = x.sort()
print(y)  # output = None
```

I was expecting the output to be [1,2,3], but instead I get None. *Please note: I am aware of how to get the correct output now but am still curious about what is happening here for the output to be none.*
In my mind, the second line evaluates
x.sort() as [1,2,3], and then this be assigned to variable y.

Comment: Thanks guys, so the answer is because sort doesn't return a list. Sorry I can't give votes but that settles in my mind

Comment: @user3880632 Exactly, if you want to store it to another var you could use `sorted()` as I described in the answer below.

Comment: As far as first questions go, I've seen a lot worse! Have my upvote <3

Comment: @Blacksilver Ah, I got your back on this one!

Comment: @Blacksilver I said the same thing. no reason to downvote. Perfectly valid question and its not a duplicate either. I would think coming from another programming language the  fact that the return value is `None` can often throw off people specially around mutability of data structures

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for list tells you that calling the sort method on a list will do an INPLACE sort. I.E it will sort the values inside the current object. Thus it doesnt return any value for you to store in y.

```
>>> x = [3,1,2]
>>> x.sort()
>>> print(x)
[1, 2, 3]
```

However you may have a legitimate reason to want to sort the list of X without actually changing it and instead store the sorted output as a new object. You can do this by passing X to sorted function

```
>>> x = [3,1,2]
>>> y = sorted(x)
>>> print(x, y)
[3, 1, 2] [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Worth noting: the lack of return value from `.sort()` is a feature; it's there to remind users that sorting is a side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

OP: *I was expecting the output to be [1,2,3] but instead I get none.*

Ans: because it does **not** return a list, rather just sorts it.

Hence:

```
x = [3,1,2]
x.sort()
print(x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

EDIT:

But if you must assign it to `y`, you could create a new sorted list and then assign it:

```
x = [3,1,2]
y = sorted(x)
print(y)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I am  not the downvoter but why would you write your own sorted function when python already provides one that is probably faster. `sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list`

Comment: I've not downvoted you. But I think is because you defined your own sorted function, when there is the built-in function `sorted` which do exactly the same thing.

Comment: FML. too much of caffeine for the day, fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code should be

```
x= [3,1,2]
x.sort()
print(x)
```

Output

```
 [1,2,3]
```

There is no need to assign `x.sort()` to y

If you want to assign to other variable use:

```
x= [3,1,2]
y=x.sorted()
print(y)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> Python lists have a built-in [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method that modifies the list in-place. There is also a [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) built-in function that builds a new sorted list from an iterable.

Source: [Python3 sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

---

Try this:

```
x = [3,1,5,2,4]
print("x         =", x)
print("sorted(x) =", sorted(x))
print("x         =", x)
print("x.sort()  =", x.sort())
print("x         =", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) in the documentation:

> This method modifies the sequence in place for economy of space when
>   sorting a large sequence. To remind users that it operates by side
>   effect, **it does not return the sorted sequence** (use sorted() to
>   explicitly request a new sorted list instance).

This is why your `y` ends up being `None`.

```
x= [3,1,2]
y = sorted(x)
print(y)
```

works, as `sorted` returns the sorted list and doesn't sort in-place.

Comment: Do you mean `y = sorted(x)`? Because as far as I know, list do not have a `sorted` method. `sorted` is a buil-in function.

Comment: @Valentino Edited it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with mutability of python objects. `List` is mutable. The `sort()` method does an `in-place` change to the list `x` and does not `return`  a copy of the object. Hence your `y` is `None`. However if you inspect `x` itself it has  been modified and no longer holds the original list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why what you're doing is not working is that the method `sort()` does not return anything. Instead, it applies itself to the object which calls it (in this case `x`), but does not return any result.

You can verify this with `print(x.sort())`, which returns `None`.

To achieve what you'd like to do, you could first copy x: `y = x.copy()`, then sort y: `y.sort()`.
Here you're able to check that `x` is still equal to `[3,1,2]`, while `y` equals `[1,2,3]`